# archive for Publishing Xamarin IOS App from Visual studio windows does not work

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to archive my Xamarin Ios project from my window 10 visual studio connected with a mac ssh on macincloud. I would to publish my app on  appstore but I got an error when archiving it

I have done all the steps about (https://developer.apple.com/) and I have created the certificate and profiles using automatic provisionning of VS Xamarin IOS

Here is my screen :

[image]
Here is my second screen :
[image]

Here is my error :

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the error?  You will need at least one Apple device registered into your Appl developer account

Comment: Open your keychain on mac, and check if the certification you selected in VS is available

Comment: @Paulw11 I have registered my Iphone

Comment: @Shaw yes it available and have passed it to trust all

Comment: Did you manually change that to "trust all"? Could try to delete and download from xocde.

Comment: @Shaw I have manuelly change to trust all.  Please download what from xcode ? on S windows there is not xcode

Comment: Sorry, my last comment is incorrect. What I did (checked my logs) is to recreate the certificates from VS on Windows, and "certification is valid" displayed on mac without manually changing anything. And I updated the profiles on the [apple dev](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list), switch to Manual Provisioning, and run.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to be considered here

1. Automatic publishing needs a registered device in apples developer portal with a valid UUID.
2. Automatic publishing is for development , manual is for distribution
3. Follow the Microsoft guide for publishing ( different for distribution). States it has to be manual and gives some settings for publish configuration.
4. Update the apple certificate that has expired in Feb 2022 in keychain to the latest 2030). Apple worldwide authority
5. Open iTunes on windows machine and make sure to accept the newer terms and conditions (nightmare to find that)
6. Make sure your bundle I'd matches what you setup in the portal. Com.companyname.appname

Im also getting the code sign 1 error , above is all the things I've had to do these last 3 days and still no success.

I have put visual studio on my Mac and it's actually giving more details to the error. Appears to be failing with a reference. Might want to try that with your app of you have a Macbook.

The process is very clunky, same on you Microsoft